# Failed Manage.py runserver command

Tags: django, web, exception, server, pycharm

I'm a beginner in web development. I'm using pycharm and django 2.1 framework
I installed django using ('py -m pip install django==2.1') and it is done.
I started myweb project using ('py -m django-admin startproject myweb .') and it also done
but when I try ('manage.py runserver') command, this is the result:

```
    (venv) C:\Users\مرحبا\PycharmProjects\Myweb>manage.py runserver
    Watching for file changes with StatReloader
    Performing system checks...

    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
    March 27, 2020 - 20:08:58
    Django version 3.0.4, using settings 'myweb.settings'
    Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
    Exception in thread <bound method Thread.name of <Thread(django-main-thread, 
    started 
    daemon 5152)>>:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\threading.py", line 917, in 
    _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
    packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 139, in inner_run
    ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 206, in run
    httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\site- 
    packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\socketserver.py", line 449, in 
    __init__
    self.server_bind()
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 
    50, 
    in server_bind
    HTTPServer.server_bind(self)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\http\server.py", line 139, in 
    server_bind
    self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)
    File "C:\Users\مرحبا\AppData\Local\Programs\lib\socket.py", line 680, in getfqdn
    aliases.insert(0, hostname)
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

In the last line of the error it says

```
aliases.insert(0, hostname) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'
```

Your Aliases variables is a string, not a list, so you can't .insert() to it, as that functionality doesn't exist.

You need to make sure Aliases is a list in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much . I made malaise = empty list and it's done thanks a lot it is a great site to help

Comment: I made an empty list

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.